# In Unit Laundry Room Stacking Washer/Dryer for Apartment

Tags: laundry

I'm currently looking at apartments for when I move out of my parents house, and my two top picks for apartments have hook ups for a washer and dryer. One of them, the laundry area is for a stackable unit. Those are fairly expensive so I was wondering if there was some sort of stand or something that I could build or even something I could buy to put the dryer on so that a top loading washer could still be put in. I've seen some small homes and condos with a shelf so non stacking washer/dryers can be placed vertically instead of horizontally. This is all a money saving issue because I really don't want to spend an extra $300 each for a stackable washer/dryer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. With what we know, all we could answer would be "it depends". Safely supporting a full-size dryer could be a significant project.

Answer (score 1):

First, congrats on the very big leap up, skipping clear over the "housemate shares and buying used stuff on Craigslist" phase of young life.

That space is not intended for stackable separate washer/dryers, which are a recent "fad" that are a side effect of the trend to front-load washers (also a deluxe item).

That space is for pre-built washer-dryer combos, which are simply a washer and dryer pre-stacked onto one chassis, [like this unit](https://www.sears.com/kenmore-417-61732j-61732-3.9-cu-ft/p-A023306851?sid=IDx01192011x000001x1627881109&utm_campaign=9031977&utm_group=65654893167-311487120398&utm_term=pla-647425770432&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIp-yJzZ2E3wIVBbbACh26CAwQEAQYAiABEgJUwPD_BwE#Imagezoom). These units are a stock-and-trade of rental units and condos.  Most are small capacity to make them narrow; large capacity units can be had.

[image]

*Note the wedge opening that allows access to the top loading washer on the bottom...*

Lately, however, the new trend is for "washer-dryer all-in-one" units, which seem to defy the laws of physics! They place washer and dryer function in a unit the form-factor of a washer.  Put clothes in dry, they come out washed *and* dry.  All the rage on tiny houses, boats, etc. I'm skittish of [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UT8NYUG) because of its low price, but there you go...

[image]

*Dirty clothes go in, dry clothes come out...*

Keep in mind ordinary wear and tear should not be counted against you, as a result many tenants get their entire deposit back. But you do not have any legal right to modify your apartment, and you will pay the full cost of restoring your apartment to *status quo ante*, which will be billed to you if the deposit doesn't cover it.

Comment: Yeah I've seen both of those and looked at those as an option. The one on the bottom is very popular in europe because it saves on space. Both of them are more expensive than buying a separate basic washer and dryer for like $400 each. (at least from what i've googled lol). If I do have to end up buying one of the prestack units, I'll probably buy used. I was just curious if it would be possible to build a shelf or something to accommodate non stacked units without ruining the walls. I'm not moving out for awhile, so I got time. Thanks for your suggestions though!